# Sending order notifications to the user to the billing email address and to the client profile email address Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Sending order notifications to the user to the billing email address and to the client profile email address.

When I create an order in the backend Woocommerce, I select an existing user on the site, this user has different emails in the profile and in the billing.

By default, order details are sent only to the billing address, but I need to duplicate them to the customer profile address as well.

How can I do that in Woocommerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin like "WooCommerce Custom Order Status Email" or "WooCommerce Order Status Control" to add a custom email notification that is sent to the customer profile email address when a specific order status is updated. You can also use the WooCommerce action hooks to programmatically add a second email recipient for order notifications.

You can add this code to your functions.php file:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'add_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function add_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $recipient .= ',' . $user->user_email;
    return $recipient;
}
```

This will add the customer profile email address as a second recipient for new order notifications.